# Why are the particles identified that way in the MSSM?

Tags: supersymmetry, mssm

In the MSSM the known fermions are the h=1/2 part of a h=0, h=1/2 multiplet.  The gauge bosons are the h=1 part of a h=1, h=1/2 multiplet.

Why is it this way round?  Why are the fermions not part of a h=1/2 h=1 multiplet just like the gauge bosons and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the vector multiplet (gauge boson + fermion) is required to be in a real representation of the gauge group, while the standard model fermoins are not.